# How to execute two instructions in a .Do()?

Tags: c++, hippomocks

I would like to execute multiple instructions inside of a .Do().

Something like:

```
mocks.ExpectCallFunc(mockedFunc).Do(a++;someFunc();)
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: I don't know this framework, but if you can call a function there, then lambda should work as well. (still a function-like element, but can be defined inline and doesn't have any name).

Comment: Use a comma, instead of a semicolon? I can only guess, since I do not see the function definition

Comment: Don't know about hippomocks, but gmock has `DoAll()`

Comment: @ArminMontigny Doubt that works since it appears to take a function pointer (or possibly object, who knows). You could add a comma operator between the two and it would compile but that would just discard the first function.

Comment: Are you compiling this as C or C++? The potential solutions to this problem are _very_ different in both cases (well, nonexistent for C)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a function to wrap what you need (bit of a overhead if its a function + a++), or you can create and pass a Lambda.

e.g. -

```
auto additionalFunc = [](<mockedFunc's arguments>) { a++; doFunc() ;};    
mocks.ExpectCallFunc(mockedFunc).Do(additionalFunc)
```

Note that your lambda must return and accept same type arguments as the mockedFunc (even if it doesn't use them).
So if the function you are mocking is **bool mockedFunc(std::string&)**

```
auto additionalFunc = [](std::string&) { a++; doFunc() ; return true;};
```

If you can't use lambda expressions (C++ < 11) then you should probably create a function packing the 2 options you need. Same guidelines apply (keep return value and arguments)